# Why is this ground check that came with the starter asssets so buggy?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The groundCheck that came with the starter assets isn't working anymore. It's jittery, and says it's grounded when it's in the air and says it's not grounded when its on the ground sometimes.
`Vector3 spherePosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y GroundedOffset, transform.position.z); Grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(spherePosition, GroundedRadius, GroundLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);`

Comment: Two things, try different options of QueryTriggerInteraction and double check your GroundLayers and GroundOffset.

Comment: what is the best groundOffset? I use the default value of -0,14. also I tried a bunch of QueryTriggerInteraction options but none of them worked.

Comment: You still here? its been a while

Comment: You still stuck on this problem. Can feel for you man... let me see your ground layers in inspector.

Comment: here are my layers : Everything, Nothing, 0: Default, 1: TransparentFX, 2: Ignore Raycast, 3: ground, 4: Water, 5: UI, 6: enemy, 7: Player(for enemy pathfinding), 8: obstacle(also for enemy pathfinging)

Comment: Try entering a tilde i.e '~' before GroundLayers. Raycast system behaves in strange ways sometimes.

Comment: so like "~ground"

Comment: As in 
Grounded = Physics.CheckSphere(spherePosition, GroundedRadius, ~GroundLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

Comment: It didn't work, it made my character not grounded more that grounded (its random)

Comment: I removed the tilde and now it only works if I'm looking up